# How to make Localization update believe that the translation of a local .po-file is not up to date?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I use a *local* development branch of a contributed project on several sites. The strings that need translation does not exist on https://localize.drupal.org/ (yet), so I cannot use it to translate the project.

Checking l10n update status produces:

```
$ drush l10n-update-status
…
my_project (7.x-1.x)   Up to date
…
```

Now, how do I convince [**Localization update**](https://www.drupal.org/project/l10n_update) that the translation of this file is *not* up to date?

So far I've tried:

- Editing and saving (i.e. changing the last updated timestamp).
- Editing the embedded timestamps `POT-Creation-Date` and `PO-Revision-Date`.
- Clearing the cache.

But no joy. **Localization update** keeps insisting that translations from this file is up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out!

*After* changing the last updated timestamp for, you need to refresh the information.  The following sequence of commands works:

```
$ touch my_project.7.x-1.x.nb.po
$ drush l10n-update-refresh
$ drush l10n-update-status
…
my_project (7.x-1.x)   Local update available
…
```

Editing the embedded timestamps `POT-Creation-Date` and `PO-Revision-Date` is not required and have no effect.